# Terminate the function in Web Service if exceed 5minutes

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services

How to terminate a function and return a response in webservice if the function doesn't completed in 5 minutes?

I have no idea on how to do this.. I saw some example is using thread so below is something that i tried so far:

```
public void myfunction(){
    Thread workerThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
    bool finished = ExecuteWithTimeLimit(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30000), () =>
    {
       .....long time execution here....

    });

    if (!finished)
    {
        workerThread.Abort();
    }
}


public static bool ExecuteWithTimeLimit(TimeSpan timeSpan, Action codeBlock)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread workerThread = new Thread(() => codeBlock());
            workerThread.Start();

            bool finished = workerThread.Join(timeSpan);


            return finished;

        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            throw ae.InnerExceptions[0];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks "almost good", but look at Thread workerThread = Thread.CurrentThread; and workerThread.Abort(); - it's wrong. How do you expect to return something by aborting current thread? Also void myfunction() - What do you expect as return value from void?